# Properly passing values between windows c# wpf without binding

Tags: c#, wpf, events, window

I have a window Window1

```
 Window1 posta= new Window1();
 posta.ShowDialog();
```

I proceed to work with some variables in `posta`. I would like to return the resulting variables / the entire method to `MainWindow`.
I know i could have global variables in `posta` and then retrieve them trough

```
 if(posta.DialogResult()==true){
   int wantedValue = posta.varResult; // varResult being the global variable of Window1
 };
```

but that seems as a bad and inefficient approach.
 I tried the following with having a button in Window1 called `myButton`

```
 Window1 posta= new Window1();
 posta.myButton.MouseRightButtonDown += myButton_RMBdown;
 posta.ShowDialog();


public void myButton_RMBdown(object Sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){
// can access MainWindow variables but cant get to Window1 variables
}
```

Would any one be so kind to help?

Edit: Without the use of databinding

Comment: add your variables to MainWIndow constructor

Comment: @apomene That works if he closes his MainWindow, but it won't if he wants to keep his MainWindow open.

Comment: You can call windows by parameters and return value that you need. but in contractor of that windows, you have to define parameters and type of return value.

Comment: Create a view model. Search the web for MVVM and WPF Data Binding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a custom modal popup window in WPF and have it return a value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540674/how-do-i-make-a-custom-modal-popup-window-in-wpf-and-have-it-return-a-value)

Comment: Why does int wantedValue = posta.varResult; seem like a bad or inefficient approach.  And it is a public property.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow an MVVM approach, you would create a ViewModel, invoke your dialog setting it's DataContext property to your ViewModel then query the ViewModel instance after ShowDialog completes. Your dialog view would then bind to the view model via Xaml

```
Window1 posta = new Window1();
var viewModel = new MyWindowViewModel();
posta.DataContext = viewModel;
posta.myButton.MouseRightButtonDown += myButton_RMBdown;
if (posta.ShowDialog())
{
    // Do things with the result
    viewModel.SomeProperty...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get parent of a control using `VisualTreeHelper`. So having the `sender` (which is the button) you can access the `Window1` like this:

```
//Some where in the MainWindow
public void myButton_RMBdown(object Sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as Button);

    while (!(parent is Window1))
    {
        parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
    }

    (parent as Window1).DoStuff();
}
```